# How to intercept the outlook outbox send event

Tags: c#, .net, office-addins, addin-express

I have a situation where i am using the scheduled email from outlook which generally adds the email in outbox to be sent later  in this case i want to intercept the event which will be triggered whenever the scheduled email from the outbox is triggered

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are interested in the [Application.ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an `Inspector` (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the `Send` button) or when the `Send` method for an Outlook item, such as `MailItem`, is used in a program.